# extract attachments from DB to separate folders for each document

Tags: directory, extract, lotus-notes, agent

Have an assignment to do - it's to extract data from Lotus Notes DB including documents and their attachments. The purpose of this is to put it and store on the Sharepoint as a library.

So far I have managed to create a view and export the data for it to structure in Excel.

Also, I have looked up some Agents examples for extracting the attachments. With implementation of the below script, I managed to export the attachments:

```
Dim sDir As String
Dim s As NotesSession
Dim w As NotesUIWorkspace
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Sub Initialize

 Set s = New NotesSession
 Set w = New NotesUIWorkspace 
 Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
 Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
 Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
 Dim rtItem As NotesRichTextItem
 Dim RTNames List As String
 Dim DOCNames List As String
 Dim itemCount As Integer
 Dim sDefaultFolder As String
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim vtDir As Variant
 Dim iCount As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim lngExportedCount As Long
 Dim attachmentObject As Variant
 

 x = MsgBox("This action will extract all attachments From the " & CStr(dc.Count) & _
 " document(s) you have selected, And place them into the folder of your choice." & _
 Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Would you like To continue?", 32 + 4, "Export Attachments")
 If x <> 6 Then Exit Sub 

 sDefaultFolder = s.GetEnvironmentString("LPP_ExportAttachments_DefaultFolder")
 If sDefaultFolder = "" Then sDefaultFolder = "F:"
 vtDir = w.SaveFileDialog( False, "Export attachments To which folder?", "All   files|*.*", sDefaultFolder, "Choose Folder and Click Save")
 If IsEmpty(vtDir) Then Exit Sub
 sDir = StrLeftBack(vtDir(0), "\")
 Call s.SetEnvironmentVar("LPP_ExportAttachments_DefaultFolder", sDir) 

 While Not (doc Is Nothing)

  iCount = 0
  itemCount = 0
  lngExportedCount = 0
  Erase RTNames
  Erase DocNames

  'Scan all items in document
  ForAll i In doc.Items

   If i.Type = RICHTEXT Then
    Set rtItem = doc.GetfirstItem(i.Name)
    If Not IsEmpty(rtItem.EmbeddedObjects) Then
 RTNames(itemCount) = CStr(i.Name)
 itemCount = itemCount +1
    End If
   End If

  End ForAll  

  For j = 0 To itemCount-1 
   Set rtItem = Nothing
   Set rtItem = doc.GetfirstItem(RTNames(j))
   ForAll Obj In rtItem.EmbeddedObjects
    If ( Obj.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then
     Call ExportAttachment(Obj)
     Call doc.Save( False, True ) 
 'creates conflict doc if conflict exists
    End If 
   End ForAll 
  Next

  'Scan all items in document
  ForAll i In doc.Items

   If i.Type = ATTACHMENT Then

    DOCNames(lngExportedCount) = i.Values(0)
    lngExportedCount = lngExportedCount + 1

   End If

  End ForAll

  For j% = 0 To lngExportedCount-1 
   Set attachmentObject = Nothing
   Set attachmentObject = doc.GetAttachment(DOCNames(j%))
   Call ExportAttachment(attachmentObject)     
   Call doc.Save( False, True ) 
'creates conflict doc if conflict exists
  Next  

  Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
 Wend

 MsgBox "Export Complete.", 16, "Finished"

End Sub

Sub ExportAttachment(o As Variant)

Dim sAttachmentName As String
Dim sNum As String
Dim sTemp As String

sAttachmentName = sDir & "\" & o.Source
While Not (Dir$(sAttachmentName, 0) = "")
    sNum = Right(StrLeftBack(sAttachmentName, "."), 2)
    If IsNumeric(sNum) Then
        sTemp = StrLeftBack(sAttachmentName, ".")
        sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 2)
        sAttachmentName = sTemp & Format$(CInt(sNum) + 1, "##00") & _
        "." & StrRightBack(sAttachmentName, ".")
    Else
        sAttachmentName = StrLeftBack(sAttachmentName, ".") & _
        "01." & StrRightBack(sAttachmentName, ".")
    End If
Wend

Print "Exporting " & sAttachmentName
'Save the file
Call o.ExtractFile( sAttachmentName ) 

    End Sub
```

So the issue I do have right now is that these attachments are being saved to the same folder, which means that I would manually have to put them into right folders of library (several thousands). Could anyone help on how should I change the above code to have the attachments saved to separate folder for each document from DB?

Also for some reason that I cant find out below line is causing error pop up with "Object Variable not set":

```
sAttachmentName = sDir & "\" & o.Source
```

Would anyone know why it causes failure and stops the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [**MkDir**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FLSAZ_MKDIR_STATEMENT.html) statement to create directory and extract attachments in the folder. Probably write something like:

```
MkDir sDir
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code that create a new directory for each document (make sure you check if the directory exists, and preferably you make sure each directory has a unique name).

I wrote a tool like that, that exports all the fields of a document into XML, as well as attachments and embedded images. It can be set to separate each document into it's own directory.
You can read more about it ate the link below, perhaps you can get some ideas from the description. I use the UniversalID of teh document to get a unique folder name.

http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter

[image]